# Export data from Angular UI-Grid in CSV

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

We are using ui-grid in our application. We are using grouping functionality of ui-grid and it's working perfectly.
Now we are exporting it to CSV and at this point I am facing issue. It is exporting same it's showing on grid. But we don't want that group row highlighted in attached image. We are only looking for rows which contains all the data in this case count is 4. Can someone please help to fix this issue.[image]

We are using below code to export it in CSV:

```
 var exportColumnHeaders = exportService.getColumnHeaders(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
      var exportData = exportService.getData(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
      var csvContent = exportService.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, exportData, grid.options.exporterCsvColumnSeparator);
        exportService.downloadFile(fileName, csvContent, grid.options.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue by writing custom code to export in excel. I have used exceljs for that.